# How to apply css using java script

Tags: javascript

I am trying to apply CSS `display: none;` to some divs using JavaScript I have tried the following:

```js
prop = document.querySelectorAll('[data-name]');
for (let i = 0; i < prop.length; i++) {
  prop[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="_69x2sms" data-name="header">
  <div class="_18tvv4h"><a target="_blank" href=""><span>Done<span class="_qx8n3fw">Ads</span></span></a></div>
  <div class="_8sfqbvd">have fun</div>
</div>
```

Note that here all class values are dynamic

Comment: [edit] the question and add the corresponding HTML code too. To create a live code snippet click on `<>` icon in the editor toolbar at the top.

Comment: Your code is working fine .

Comment: The code, as provided, works fine. You need to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Quentin you are absolutely right.